# Bubble sort program user input

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I want the user to add any integer they want to the bubble sort array.In implementing this,I have trouble in understanding how to do so. Any coding that could help me with this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arraylist[] = {
            6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
        };
        System.out.println("Final result:" + Arrays.toString(BubbleMethod(arraylist)));

    }

    public static int[] BubbleMethod(int[] arr) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result " + (i + 1) + ": " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: ok, say for example the user inputs the number 8, i want it to be added to my array list and then get sorted into ascending order

Comment: So the question is about adding new elements dynamically to a list, you can't do that through the normal array, start using something like `ArrayList` class

Comment: could you make any changes to my coding that would help me accomplish what you are telling me i need to do?

Comment: You need a data structure that has a dynamic size.  Additionally, if you use something like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` then you can just use `Collections.sort()` (unless this is for homework...)

Comment: @RMH22 there are so many examples for what you want on the internet, just search for "java ordered list example", I found the answer there :)

Comment: _"could you make any changes to my coding"_ now you're not asking for help, you are asking someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: i have done my work for my bubble sort now i am just looking to enhance my program by adding the user input..  and i'm asking around to see if anybody has any code that will help me do so. @StephenP

Comment: @RMH22 Indeed.  But asking for us to give you these coded changes is what Stephen is referring to.  We can give you suggestions for improvement, but it is up to you to figure out how to implement those suggestions -- or come back and ask specific questions when you run into issues attempting to implement those suggestions.

Comment: Okay i'm new to java and this website, I thought it was for finding coding for my program. If you wouldn't mind could you walk me through what to do so i still understand without just taking your coding from you? @lmcphers

Comment: Well, Abdo Adel already gave you a suggestion.  He suggests changing your code to use an ArrayList instead of an Array.  This way you can add elements to it dynamically since Arrays have fixed sizes.  I would take this information and start researching how to do that.  Find out what an ArrayList is and how to use it in your code.  Find the Java documentation and see what methods you can call on arraylists.  All of this can be done through Google.  Start implementing it in your code.  You will get errors that you don't understand.  These are the questions you ask us here (assuming it hasn't

Comment: been asked already elsewhere on StackOverflow, which you can find out by Google searching your problem, as well and seeing if you get any answers that make sense to you!)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will get you desired input from user, you can modify your above code to fit my code into it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GetInput
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int howManyInteger;
    private ArrayList<Integer> intValues;

    public GetInput()
    {
        intValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("How many integer you want to enter?");
        howManyInteger = userInput.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < howManyInteger; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter value for array "+i+": ");
            intValues.add(userInput.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand an array dynamically, you should create a new array, copy all the existing array elements and add the value to be added to the head or tail. Then you can return the new array.

1) To expand an array by adding value to the head, you can use this method below;

```
// adds an integer to the head of the array, returns array with N+1 length
public static int[] addToArrayHead(int[] array, int value) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

    newArray[0] = value;

    for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    return newArray;
}
```

2) To expand an array by adding value to the tail, you can use this method below;

```
// adds an integer to the end of the array, returns array with N+1 length
public static int[] addToArrayTail(int[] array, int value) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < array.length; i++ )
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    newArray[i] = value;    //already incremented with post-increment operator

    return newArray;
}
```

With these methods, you can expand your array by head or tail, check out the code below. In this example, the array is expanding on both directions by adding '-5' to head and '99' to the tail;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arraylist[] = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        System.out.println("Final result:"
                + Arrays.toString(BubbleMethod(arraylist)));

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < arraylist.length; i++ )
            System.out.print(arraylist[i] + " ");

        arraylist = addToArrayHead(arraylist,-5);   // add to head
        arraylist = addToArrayTail(arraylist, 99);  // add to tail

        System.out.println("\nUpdated array");
        for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arraylist[i] + " " );

    }

    public static int[] BubbleMethod(int[] arr) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result " + (i + 1) + ": "
                    + Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        return arr;
    }

    // adds an integer to the end of the array, returns array with N+1 length
    public static int[] addToArrayTail(int[] array, int value) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

        int i = 0;
        for( ; i < array.length; i++ )
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        newArray[i] = value;    //already incremented with post-increment operator

        return newArray;
    }

    // adds an integer to the head of the array, returns array with N+1 length
    public static int[] addToArrayHead(int[] array, int value) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

        newArray[0] = value;

        for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        return newArray;
    }
}
```

The output of this program is as follows;

```
Result 1: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
Result 2: [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
Result 3: [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]
Result 4: [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Result 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Final result:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1 2 3 4 5 6 
Updated array
-5 2 3 4 5 6 99 0
```

To go one step further with user interaction, update expanding array as below with **null array checks**;

```
// adds an integer to the end of the array, returns array with N+1 length
public static int[] addToArrayTail(int[] array, int value) {
    //null array check
    if( array == null ) {
        array = new int[1];
        array[0] = value;

        return array;
    }

    int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < array.length; i++ )
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    newArray[i] = value;    //already incremented with post-increment operator

    return newArray;
}

// adds an integer to the head of the array, returns array with N+1 length
public static int[] addToArrayHead(int[] array, int value) {
    //null array check
    if( array == null ) {
        array = new int[1];
        array[0] = value;

        return array;
    }

    int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

    newArray[0] = value;

    for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
        newArray[i] = array[i];

    return newArray;
}
```

And the latest user input interaction functionality added code is as below.
Notice that this is the **complete code** and your **answer**;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleUserInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int[] array = initArrayWithUserInput();

        System.out.println("User Generated Array;");
        System.out.println("*********************");
        printArray(array);
        System.out.println("Sorted Array;");
        System.out.println("*************");
        printArray(BubbleMethod(array));

    }

    public static int[] BubbleMethod(int[] arr) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result " + (i + 1) + ": "
                    + Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
        return arr;
    }

    // adds an integer to the end of the array, returns array with N+1 length
    public static int[] addToArrayTail(int[] array, int value) {
        //null array check
        if( array == null ) {
            array = new int[1];
            array[0] = value;

            return array;
        }

        int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

        int i = 0;
        for( ; i < array.length; i++ )
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        newArray[i] = value;    //already incremented with post-increment operator

        return newArray;
    }

    // adds an integer to the head of the array, returns array with N+1 length
    public static int[] addToArrayHead(int[] array, int value) {
        //null array check
        if( array == null ) {
            array = new int[1];
            array[0] = value;

            return array;
        }

        int[] newArray = new int[array.length+1];

        newArray[0] = value;

        for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++ )
            newArray[i] = array[i];

        return newArray;
    }

    // initialize the array with user input
    public static int[] initArrayWithUserInput() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cont = true;
        int[] array = null;
        String choice;

        while( cont ) {
            System.out.println("Want to add element ?");
            choice = in.nextLine();
            if( choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                array = addToArrayTail( array, in.nextInt() );
                in.nextLine();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Array generated");
                cont = false;               
            }

        }

        in.close();     // close the resource to prevent resource leak

        return array;
    }

    //prints array to the console
    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%3d ", array[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The output is as follows;

```
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
6
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
4
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
5
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
3
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
1
Want to add element ?
y
Please enter an integer
2
Want to add element ?
n
Array generated
User Generated Array;
  6   4   5   3   1   2 
Sorted Array;
Result 1: [4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6]
Result 2: [4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6]
Result 3: [3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
Result 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Result 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  1   2   3   4   5   6
```